# Xpath concept confusion

Tags: xpath, nodes, ancestor

I'm stuck at trying to figure out what does the following XPath expressions lead to in XML:

1. `paper/publisher/parent::*/author`
2. `/bib//address[ancestor::book]`
3. `/bib//author/ancestor::*//zip`

1) The first is to show all the parent that has author as the root element? What does */ means

2) The second one list all the ancestor root element under book?

3) The third one I really have no clue, it list all the zip node

Just confused about how ancestor node works overall, please give some guidance.

Comment: This isn't really a tutorial site. There are pages and pages of documentation available out there for XPath; you can find them via Google.

Comment: As I explained, *this is not a tutorial site*. You were given these XPath expressions as part of your assignment, and you are the one that is expected to answer those questions. If we do it for you, you learn nothing. If you don't have the ability to answer them, ask your instructor for help. They're being paid to provide you with the knowledge needed to complete the assignment, and if you can't then they have not yet done their job.

Comment: Now I'm more confused. You not only don't have a problem, but you're expecting us to author study guides for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first XPath expression is using the `parent::` axis with an element wildcard node test. From the `publisher` element, it "jumps up" to it's parent, the `paper` element, and then selects the `author` child element. It only selects that `author` element if the `publisher` sibling is present. It could be written more compactly and avoid looking up the node tree with this XPath using a predicate filter on the `paper` element:  `paper[publisher]/author`.
2. That XPath selects all of the `address` elements that are descendants of the `bib` element and are also descendants of a `book` element(which could be the ancestor or descendant of the `bib` ancestor). The square braces are a predicate, which filters the nodes that pass the test for the expression. In this case, it must be a descendant of a `book` element in order to "pass" the test and be selected.
3. This XPath looks for any `zip` element that is the descendant of an element that is the ancestor of an `author` element that is the descendant of a `bib` element.

Below is a visualization of the XPath axes, in order to understand what it means to select an ancestor, parent, sibling, descendant, etc.

[image: visualization of XPath axes]

It might be helpful to play with an XPath visualization tool, in order to evaluate your XPath expressions against some sample XML and see what is and is not selected.

For example:
http://chris.photobooks.com/xml